# converting pointcloud data from mmwave sensor to laserscan

Tags: ros, point-clouds

I am using ti mmwave 1642 evm sensor for generation of pointcloud data. For processing the data, I am using Intel NUC.
I am facing the problem of converting pointcloud data from mmwave sensor to laserscan.
By launching `rviz_1642_2d.launch`, I am able to see pointcloud data in rviz.
How to convert the pointcloud data, generated from mmwave sensor, to laserscan?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this conversion is not straight forward since a pointcloud describes an unordered set of 3d points in the world. A laser scan, on the other hand, is a well parametrized and ordered 2d description of equiangular distance measurements.
Therefore, converting a pointcloud into a laserscan will cause a massive loss in information.
However, there are packages like [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) which does the conversion for you and furthermore, you can define how the conversion should be applied.